# Unable to lowercase the header of csv file

Tags: python, csv, lowercase

I'm trying to make the first row/header lowercase, in multiple csv files in a directory using python. The code and error are below. Is there any way to fix the code or some other way?

```
import csv
import glob

path = (r'C:\Users\Documents')

for fname in glob(path):
    with open(fname, newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        row1 = next(reader)
        for row1 in reader:
            data = [row1.lower() for row1 in row1]
            os.rename(row1, data)
```

The error is:

```
TypeError: rename: src should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not list
```

Comment: First off, this might cause an issue: for row1 in row1?

Comment: `os.rename` is for renaming files. You seem to want to perform the lower casing, something like `row1 = [entry.lower() for entry in row1]`, then write the new CSV table back to disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're getting rows and columns mixed-up. Here's some untested code that does what you want, I think:

```
import csv
from glob import glob

path = (r'C:\Users\Documents\*.csv')  # Note wildcard character added for glob().

for fname in glob(path):
    with open(fname, newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        header = next(reader)  # Get the header row.
        header = [column.lower() for column in header]  # Lowercase the headings.
        rows = [header] + list(reader)  # Read the rest of the rows.

    with open(fname, 'w', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(rows)  # Write new header & original rows back to file.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked except few changes to the code at two places

Comment: glob.glob(path) as it was throwing in error TypeError: 'module' object is not callable and other [row for row in reader ] instead reader.

Comment: Thanks. Think I got them both fixed in latest update.